# Flutter Renderboxes passing down Infinity height?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm getting confused with flutter's render boxes.
Here's what I understand: The layouting algorithm starts at the root and traverses down the widget tree, passing down constraints to the children. Flex boxes, in bounded constraints in their scroll direction, try to match their parent constraints.

Consider the following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      print("Parent");
      print(constraints.maxWidth);
      print(constraints.maxHeight);
      return Column(children: [
        LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          print("Child");
          print(constraints.maxWidth);
          print(constraints.maxHeight);
          return SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          );
        })
      ]);
    });
  }
```

This prints

```
flutter: Parent
flutter: 320.0
flutter: 568.0
flutter: Child
flutter: 320.0
flutter: Infinity
```

How does the height constraints suddenly become Infinity?
Shouldn't it match its parent and be 568.0?

Comment: I share your confusion. Shouldn't the child's maxHeight be the same as the parent's in this case? As far as I understand, this is something happens with Columns. Wrapping a Column's children with Expanded widgets will make them respect the Column's constraints. In this scenario that means wrapping the LayoutBuilders.

Answer (score 1):

LayoutBuilder parent size is important, if size of parent isn't clear, constraints sizes will be infinity. for example if you wrap your widget with scaffold, LayoutBuilder provides exact size.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it’s confusing. The Flex part of this doc helps. Once the Column is in the tree the Column tries to be “as big as possible”. Why “possible” is Infinity and not 568 in this case, I don’t know and it’s seems unnecessarily painful and complicated (unlike the rest of Flutter).

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints